# In Haskell, how to reorder multi kinded types

Tags: haskell, polykinds

Say I have a type of kind `l :: * -> * -> *`, so I need to apply 2 types for example `a`, and `b` to get a simple type `l a b`.

How can I map the type `l :: * -> * -> *` into a new type `m(l) :: * -> * -> *` where `m(l) b a` means the same as `l a b` for every `a,b` ? Here `a,b` are not constants. Is it possible? Is it wrong to think of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type M l a b = l b a 

newtype M l a b = M (l b a)
```

Or without taking `l` as parameter

```
data L a b = ... 

newtype M a b = M (L b a) 

type M a b = L b a
```

Edit:

```
type M l a b = l b a 

data L a b = L (a Int) (b Int)

type Z = M L Maybe []
```

Moreover, you can give explicit kind signatures too

```
type M  (l :: k1 -> k2 -> *) (a :: k2) (b :: k1) = l b a
```

Comment: i'm not sure if this works, I want it to work for all ```a``` and ```b``` that i may plug in later, here it seems they are constant parameters, I feel like it should only depends on ```l```. Maybe im wrong ill have to check

Comment: @J.M. `a` and `b` are parameters, not constants, in the code above.

Comment: @J.M. I don't understand your exact question but I added some clarification I though you might find helpful

Comment: In the last case I don't think `a` and `b` need to have the same kind: `type M (l :: k1 -> k2 -> *) (a :: k2) (b :: k1) = l b a `